# Inequality with function

Tags: functions

How do I find the parameter $m\in\mathbb{R}$ in the function: $f(x)=x^2-(m-1)x+3m-4$

a) Such that $f(x)=0$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $f\geq 0$ for $x\in(0,1)$

From the first one I understand that $f$ has a root in $(0,1)$ but what about the second? doesn't that mean $f'(x)\geq0$ in that interval?

b) $f(x)<0$ for $x\in(0,1)$ (I need the interval for m)

Comment: In (a), did you mean that $\;f(x)\;$ vanishes *at some point* $\;x\in (0,1)\;$ , or what?

Comment: yes,in my book it says f(x) cancels in that interval

Comment: The meaning is that it must vanish **only** at one or, at most, two points in that interval, **not at the whole** interval...unless it is the zero polynomial, which *it is not* .

Comment: Understanding what the problem is asking is half the battle. This can be made difficult with important details left out or typos. Hence the idea this is not the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For you have $f(x) = 0$ as a quadratic equation, with roots
$$
x_\pm = \frac{m-1 \pm \sqrt{(m-1)^2-4(3m-4)}}{2}
$$
and $$ \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = \infty$$ which suggests $f < 0$ between the roots and $f > 0$ to the left of $x_-$ and to the right of $x_+$.

Can you finish this?